# My radio button keeps getting displayed as a text box?

Tags: html, css

New to CSS and HTML and learning from freecodecamp.com. I wrote the following and when I execute it, the radio buttons are displayed like open text boxes. Can someone tell me why that is?

```
<htmL>
    <style>
        .red-text{
          color: red;
        }
        h1 {
           font-style: Helvetica, sans-serif;
           font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <h1 class="red-text"> Trying to learn how to be a developer in CSS<H1>
    <img src="https://wallingis.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/software-developer.png" alt:" The mind chakra of a developer ">
    <p> It is not easy when you are not from a developer background to become developer. You need time and concentration not to mention the dedication to become one. Here are two questions that I ask from a survey standpoint to understand people better.</p>
<p>Why did you chose to become a developer?</p>
<form action="/Submit answers below:">
        <label><input type=“radio” name=“Reason to be a developer” >Passion</label><br>
        <label><input type=“radio” name=“Reason to be a developer” >To be Rich</></label><br>
        <label><input type=“radio” name=“Reason to be a developer” >Family Pressure</label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Submit other thoughts" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    <p> If given the chance would you stick to the developer job or move to another profession, given that money and circumstances are in your favor?</p>
        <label><input type=“Checkbox” name=“Choice”>Yes</label><br>
        <label><input type=“Checkbox” name=“Choice”>No, would stick to this because I love it</label><br>
        <label><input type=“Checkbox” name=“Choice”>Do not know - lost in life at the moment</label><br>
    <p> One of the things we have found is that the reason people join this line of work are the following:</p>
        <ul>
            <li> More jobs are available</li>
            <li> Potential in career growth is higher than most industries due to the technological push</li>
            <li> Job stability and certainty of the fact that moving around is easy within the industry</li>
        </ul>
    <p> The median income in this category is roughly around $50k / year with huge potential of getting an increment and to grow within the industry to higher paying positions</p>

    </html>
```

Comment: Can you please also add the relevant CSS code?

Comment: The quotes are wrong. Somehow You're using the wrong symbol. It must be double or single quotes.

Comment: Updated the entire code @davideSerafini

Comment: @Skaparate: All my quotes are double - am I getting you wrong?

Comment: @KaranSingh, yes, somehow You're using the wrong symbol. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skaparate/z78owd2a/1/. It's not that you're not using double quotes, it's just a different symbol. You can validate Your code in https://validator.w3.org/ to see what's wrong :).

Comment: @Skaparate: Thank you so much! The Mac had a weird keyboard feature that made the quotes look different. The code worked once I changed it! Thank you for making this less frustrating and helping me so quickly!

Comment: @KaranSingh, glad I could help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give You a better answer, following My comments.

Check the differences in Your own code:

```
<h1 class="red-text"> Trying to learn how to be a developer in CSS<H1>
```

Here You're using the right symbol, but here:

```
<label><input type=“Checkbox” name=“Choice”>Yes</label><br>
```

The quotes seems to be *to the left* (”), while the first ones are straight (").